# Animating button presses / clicks in Android

Tags: android, animation, user-interface

I'm trying to create a button-click animation, e.g. the button scales down a little when you press it, scales back up when you release. If you simply tap, you get the press and release strung together.

I set up an onTouchListener and a couple XML-defined AnimatorSets, one for the press and one for the release. Ran the press on `ACTION_DOWN`, the release on `ACTION_UP` or `ACTION_CANCEL`. This works fine when you press and hold the button, then release a little later. But with a quick tap, the release animation triggers before the press one is done, and often the result is no animation at all.

I'd hoped I could use AnimatorSet's sequential capabilities to stick the release animation onto the end of the possibly-already-running press animation, but no luck. I'm sure I could rig something up with callbacks, but that seems messy.

What's the best approach here? Thanks!

Answer (score 5):

I built a sample Button class that buffers animations and executes them in a queue according to what you need:

```
public class AnimationButton extends Button 
{
    private List<Animation> mAnimationBuffer = new ArrayList<Animation>();;
    private boolean mIsAnimating;

    public AnimationButton(Context context) 
    {
        super(context);

    }

    public AnimationButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs) 
    {
        super(context, attrs);

    }

    public AnimationButton(Context context, AttributeSet attrs, int defStyle) 
    {
        super(context, attrs, defStyle);

    }


    @Override
    public boolean onTouchEvent(MotionEvent event) 
    {
        if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN)
        {
            generateAnimation(1, 0.75f);
            triggerNextAnimation();
        }
        else if (event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_CANCEL || event.getAction() == MotionEvent.ACTION_UP)
        {
            generateAnimation(0.75f, 1);
            triggerNextAnimation();
        }

        return super.onTouchEvent(event);
    }

    private void generateAnimation(float from, float to)
    {
        ScaleAnimation scaleAnimation = new ScaleAnimation(from, to, from, to);
        scaleAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
        scaleAnimation.setDuration(500);
        scaleAnimation.setAnimationListener(new ScaleAnimation.AnimationListener() 
        {       
            @Override
            public void onAnimationStart(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationRepeat(Animation animation) { }

            @Override
            public void onAnimationEnd(Animation animation) 
            {               
                mIsAnimating = false;
                triggerNextAnimation();
            }
        });

        mAnimationBuffer.add(scaleAnimation);
    }

    private void triggerNextAnimation()
    {
        if (mAnimationBuffer.size() > 0 && !mIsAnimating)
        {
            mIsAnimating = true;
            Animation currAnimation = mAnimationBuffer.get(0);
            mAnimationBuffer.remove(0);

            startAnimation(currAnimation);
        }
    }

}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Yeah, this is the sort of manual implementation I was thinking about...but was hoping there was something more concise and built in.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like L Preview adds the ability to specify animations for state changes in the xml file.

https://developer.android.com/preview/material/animations.html#viewstate