# Android button press and release animation

Tags: android, android-animation

I'm trying to make the buttons within my app animate like this:

-Whenever you *touch* the button (action down) it will scale smaller (from 1.0 to 0.8, for example) and will stay shrank.

-Whenever you *release* the button, it will go back to its full size and stay like this.

-Only after the two animations occurred, the function of the button will be called.

I've tried using the following method: https://stackoverflow.com/a/19261773/9183824

but it made the animation weird and buggy, the button only shrinks and then goes back to its full size even before I release and without any animation.

I would love to know how to implement an animation like this properly.

Comment: You're mixing `animation` with `functionality requirement`

Comment: That is because implementing the animation might be different if I need the function to go only afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

Hey in case you are still looking for a solution, use this library i created for the same scenario

```
implementation 'com.github.saurabhdhillon:anim-press-view:0.0.1'
```

This is still under development but Button, CardView and ConatinerLayout works fine for the use case you want. 
Update me if you need some more changes to customise this.